# Как увеличить картинки?

Tags: wordpress

Сделано через приложение tabs responsive
Код: https://pastebin.com/Se5PwE4X
Не могу понять как увеличить сами картинки. В коде, судя по элементу, всё правильно делаю, но почему-то сами картинки не увеличиваются в блоке. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть.

Сайт, где требуется помощь: http://lascala-shop.ru/

[image: в коде правлю, эффекта никакого нет]

Comment: Разрещение самих картинок какое?

Comment: Какртинки сами 443х197 . Их невозможно растянуть?

Comment: @user239511 в css впишите этот код, не переписывая оригинальный код, просто скопируйте и вставьте код в файл css.. У меня работает, у вас нет, как-то странно.

Comment: @user239511 в остальном.. Кривое построение почти везде в плане инженерии. Загрузка долгая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри какая большая конструкция для картинок, слишком много блоков у тебя. Код:

```
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
<div class="brands-outbox">
<div class="brands-cart">
<img src="http://lascala-shop.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/77-1.png">
<div class="brands-cart-hover">
<p>emporio armani</p>
<hr>
<a href="http://lascala-shop.ru/?brand=emporio-armani">Посмотреть коллекцию</a>
</div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Не буду критиковать.
**Подойдёт такое решение:**

```
.brands-cart, .brands-cart img, .brands-outbox, .brands-cart-hover {
width: 650px !important;
height: 300px !important;
}

.brands-cart img {
object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Так я тоже пробовал. Не помогает. Касательно большого блока - это конструктор, он создаёт всё это... Если бы я писал, то разумеется гораздо проще было бы)

Comment: @user239511 у меня работает.

Comment: @user239511 в css впишите этот код, не переписывая оригинальный код, просто скопируйте и вставьте код в файл css.. У меня работает, у вас нет, как-то странно.

Comment: @user239511 Ты что-то неправильно делаешь. С помощью браузера. Ты ведь не разработчик. Используешь готовые плагины. Если я сделаю, вставлю куда надо данный css, то работать будет.

Comment: @user239511 Вообще я бы на твоем месте не использовал вордпресс с кривыми плагинами. В всяком случае решать тебе.

Comment: да это я знакомому правил сайт... Спасибо, Владимир!